# PCA : how to cluster data to differenciate my data the most while considering their groups

Tags: r, pca, biostatistics

I have to do a PCA in R for a project, but I have 300 data in 15 different groups, and I want to find the variables which gives me the most variability between the groups and cluster my data in their own group ( so not between all the data) so I can do an analysis later while using these variables (I have 4000 very similar variables).

Each of my variables represent a different wavelenght from spectral data, and my different groups represent different species. I took spectral data of several individuals of each species. My objective is to find the reduced space that represent most of the variability between my groups to do an ANOVA with the result of my PCA later

I know how to do the analysis when I want to cluster data that are not already in a group, but I don't know how to do it when I want to find out which variable can separate my groups the best.

Comment: This is not entirely clear, can you tell us about the applied context? What does your variables represent, what defines the groups, and what is your applied goal?  But maybe look into canonical correlations analysis ...

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think your question may contain a misconception. The result of PCA are n components which are mutually independent, resulting from rotations in euclidian space. These rotations remove any interpretability in terms of the original independent variables. 

Your best bet is to take different attributes of your datapoints, combine them for a PCA analysis, and see which combination of independent variables produces the highest amount of explained variance for a fixed amount of components (eg 3). However, the utility of this depends on what you do with that info.